# Unexpected token, expected "..."

Tags: reactjs, unexpected-token, unstated

I got the error: `Unexpected token, expected "..."`

I use react unstated.

My code:

```
 return (
      <Subscribe to {[ChatContainer]}>
        {chatProvider => (
          <>
            Hello World
          </>
        )
        }
      </Subscribe>
    )
```

I could find solutions for `expected ";"` but not for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put `=` between `to` prop and its value